# Alternative IDE for Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, ide

I want to play around with silverlight without having to buy a Visual Studio 2008 license.
I already used my trial time with Visual Studio, so I'm trying to find another solution.

Any thing out there?

Thanks

Comment: On a related not, Silverlight 2 RTW is to be released tomorrow (10/14/2008) so you'll want to check for newer tools releases then to work with the final release.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Visual Web Developer Express SP1 is supported with RC0 and later. Install it first, then install the tools.

Comment: I see, I installed Web Developer but was unaware that I had to install   other tools. Thank you Bill.

Answer (score 1):

What I heard, you can use VS Express SP1 with Silverlight.

Answer (score 1):

Use **Eclipse**

**[Eclipse tools for Microsoft Silverlight](http://www.eclipse4sl.org/)**  check out http://www.eclipse4sl.org/

Comment: Link is no longer active.