# Silverlight IDE for latest version (May 2010)

Tags: silverlight, ide, moonlight

In 2008 [Artur Carvalho](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1013/artur-carvalho) asked for an [Alternative IDE for Silverlight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/197703/alternative-ide-for-silverlight) and was told to [look at Visual Studio Express](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/197703/alternative-ide-for-silverlight/197915#197915).

Is that still the valid answer in 2010 or are there other IDEs one should consider (cost/ OS it runs on / stability)?

I'm trying to get a feel for silverlight development before commiting cash. So I don't need enterprize level tools or a license to distribute ..

Would MonoDevelop and Moonlight be an option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Windows I haven't heard about anything besides [Visual Studio Express 2010](http://www.microsoft.com/Express/). On Mac you can use [Eclipse for Silverlight](http://www.eclipse4sl.org/).

As for me, I don't develop SL daily rather occasionally and starting with Blend 3 I can actually use Blend for most of my smaller personal projects and don't bother to install VS although I have a licence for it. Blend now has a decent support for Intellisense and most UI stuff is easier in Blend. Yes, Blend is not free.